# Why does the AzureRmWebAppDeploymen ask for my subscription and then try and use it as a service connection?

Tags: azure-devops

My YAML is

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<mysubscription>'
    WebAppName: 'mylinuxapi'
    Package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

Where  is the subscription id

When I run the build the error is

```
Job Job1:Step input azureSubscription references service connection
The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
```

[image: build error]

[Update]

I am now trying to find how to add a new service end point
[image: service connections]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636120/how-do-i-switch-the-default-branch-in-my-azure-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636906/why-wont-my-service-connection-stay-verified

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=vsts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637267/save-is-disabled-for-build-pipeline

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the **Resource authorization** issue. Please see [Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=vsts) and try the workaround ([`Troubleshooting authorization for a YAML pipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=vsts#troubleshooting-authorization-for-a-yaml-pipeline)) to fix the issue.

Some resources **must be authorized** before they can be used. This ensures that only users with sufficient permissions can access potentially sensitive resources such as service connections.

> **Resource authorization**
>
> When you save a pipeline, resource authorization checks for new and
>   updated resources. If you lack permission to authorize one or more
>   resources, then saving the pipeline will fail.
>
> If you add a new resource to an existing YAML pipeline, Azure
>   Pipelines will pick up the change but may not be able to authorize
>   resources. Your builds may fail until you authorize resources using
>   the troubleshooting steps below.
>
> **Troubleshooting authorization for a YAML pipeline:**
>
> When you add a new service endpoint or other resource to a pipeline,
>   it must be authorized before it will work. If builds fail with an
>   error message about resource authorization, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Navigate to the pipeline in the web.
> 2. Switch the default branch to the branch that includes the new
>      service endpoint reference.
> 3. Save the pipeline.
> 4. Revert back to the original default branch and save the pipeline
>      again.

Comment: Thank you but where is the "new service endpoint reference" in terms of the repository branch?

Comment: Also, how do I switch the default branch?

Comment: @KirstenGreed Just try to create a new service endpoint.... point to it --> Save pipeline --> Then revert back to the original one --> Save the pipeline again.

Comment: @KirstenGreed Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts

Comment: I can't see anything about endpoints. I updated the question. Is an endpoint the same thing as a service connection?

Comment: Yeah, it's the service connection

Comment: I followed the instructions but I still get the error. I see the YAML does not refer to a service connection. It refers to a subscription so how can it use a service connection?

Comment: @KirstenGreed You need to create the service connection first then [Use the service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#use-a-service-connection) in YAML.

Comment: So an end point is a service connection is a subscription, but I pay for subscriptions, no wonder I am confused.

Comment: @KirstenGreed Yeah, in previous version of TFS/VSTS the name is `service endpoint` and in current Azure DevOps the name is changed to `service connection` ...

Comment: and the prompt is Subscription (sigh)

Comment: For step 2, on Azure Devops currently click "Edit" on the build pipeline, click the "Edit in the visual designer" link on the page, click on "Get sources". Here you can change the default branch.