# How do I switch the default branch for my build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am [working on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583903/why-does-the-azurermwebappdeploymen-ask-for-my-subscription-and-then-try-and-use) and I need to switch the default branch of my Azure Repository.

How do I do this?

I can see where to switch the Compare tag but not the Default tag.

[image: branches]

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Get Sources properties, which can be accessed when editing the YAML pipeline, entering the "Triggers" menu at the top right corner:

[image: here in the pipeline]

Comment: Where is this? (Found, must edit the pipeline to see this screen.) How can I do it in the YAML?

Comment: @DavidCobb On the screen where you can edit the YAML file you can select 'Triggers' in the top-right menu. This will lead you to the screen that is shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article on how to do this: https://mattvsts.blogspot.com/2019/03/did-you-know-changing-default-and.html

The basic gist is to go to the repository settings in your project, then find your branch and right click to set as the default branch.

Answer (score 2):

Go to - Manage Repositories as  shown in the [Manage Repositories Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt7uc.png)

After this, it should be easy to figure out.

Click on Repos => Repositories
Find out your repo and the branch you want to make default. Right click on it and you will get the option 'set as default branch'