# Why won't my service connection stay verified?

Tags: azure-devops

I am [working on this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583903/why-does-the-azurermwebappdeploymen-ask-for-my-subscription-and-then-try-and-use) and want to ensure my service connection is verified.

[image]

When I click Verify Connection I do get a green connection verified tick.
[image: verified]

Then I close the dialog

When I open the dialog again it says the connection is not verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am actually able to build a release i guess that this is just a strange behaviour in the UI