# Save is disabled for build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have filled in all the options for my build pipeline and there  no error messages.
How do I go about finding out why the Save button is disabled?

[image: build pipeline]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/203956/build-definition-buttons-are-greyed-out.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583903/why-does-the-azurermwebappdeploymen-ask-for-my-subscription-and-then-try-and-use/52603270?noredirect=1#comment92210046_52603270

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I go to Triggers on the top menu then I can see some settings need attention under Continuous Integration.

The little red error icon is actually visible against the word trigger in my screen shot.

"You must add at least one branch filter."

Once I add a branch filter the save button enables.

Comment: but add button is also disabled for branch filter. how can i edit existing task? everything is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was because I didn't have sufficient permissions for the project.

Once I was given permissions, I had to leave the 'create pipeline editor' and then create a new one and now the 'Save & Queue' option is enabled along with all the other fields.

This seems like an Azure bug. They let you into the Pipeline editor when you shouldn't have access to it via the plus icon next to the Project Name as seen in the image. After you enable permissions and click on 'Pipeline' (left nav), you are presented with a UI for creating pipelines that wasn't there before. Before getting permissions, you are presented with a blank screen when clicking on Pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, I had the same problem, and something else fixed mine. After I clicked the "View YAML" link, the Save button was enabled, and the red warning message went away. **I have no idea why.** Just putting this out there in case it helps someone else. In case MS reads this: *ability to edit the full YAML for release pipelines (just like we can for build pipelines) would be nice.*